# Using jQuery to upload a photo simply reloads the page instead of running the function

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I'm trying to make a popup form that utilized jQuery and PHP to upload a photo to the server and make a database entry about the photo.

What is wanted:
-User uploads a photo. Anything else other than .jpg/.jpeg is rejected.
-Photo is resized to 1000x1000 and 250x250. The original file is destroyed.
-The photo and the thumb are sent to their respective folders (uploads and uploads/thumbs).
-Mysql declares the new files in the database, including title, description, time.

It simply reloads the page instead. Here is my code so far. Most of the PHP code is required to use (the image editing part)

HTML

```
<div class="popup popup2 flex-enable" data-popup="popup-2">
            <div class="popup-inner flex-center">
                <h2 class="small-white-title textcenter">Upload a photo</h2>
                <hr>
                <div class="flex-enable">
                    <form class="flex-enable flex-column flex-center" id="uploadForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="small-white-subtitle form-label flex-column flex-center textcenter">
                        <label for="title">Τίτλος Φωτογραφίας</label>
                        <input class="form-input-large small-white-title" type="text" id="phototitle" name="title" placeholder="Γράψτε εδώ τον τίτλο...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-white-subtitle form-label flex-column flex-center">
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile" />
                        <label id="uploadPhoto" for="file">Επιλέξτε αρχείο<br></label>
                        <div id="message"></div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="small-white-subtitle form-label flex-column flex-center textcenter">
                        <label for="description">Περιγραφή Φωτογραφίας</label>
                        <input class="form-input-large small-white-title" type="text" id="photodesc" name="photodesc" placeholder="Γράψτε εδώ μία περιγραφή...">
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" >
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset" >
                    </form>
                </div>
                <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-2" href="#">×</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JQ

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('drop dragover',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('input[type=file]').on('change',anevase);
});

function anevase(event){
    $sanitizedFilename = event.target.value.replace("C:\\fakepath\\","");
    $("#uploadPhoto").html($sanitizedFilename);
    file = event.target.files[0];
    var data = new FormData();
    if (!file.type.match('image/jpg') || !file.type.match('image/jpeg')){
        $("uploadPhoto").html("Please select a jpg file");
    }
    else if(file.size>5000000){
        $("uploadPhoto").html("Please select a smaller file (<5 MB)");
    }
    else{
        data.append('file', file, file.name);
        var xhr = new XMLHTTPRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php', true);
        xhr.send(data);
        xhr.onload = function(){
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            if(xhr.status === 200 && response.status == 'ok'){
                $("#uploadPhoto").html("File has been uploaded successfully.")
            }
            else if(response.status == 'type_err'){
                $("#uploadPhoto").html("Please choose an images file. Click to upload another.");
            }
            else{
                $("#uploadPhoto").html("Some problem occured, please try again.");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
require('connect.php');

function makeImage($imgfile, $imgname, $inputWidth, $inputHeight, $path){

    $saving_path = $path."/".$imgname;
    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgfile);    
    $size= getimagesize($imgfile);
    $width = $size[0];
    $height = $size[1];

    $finalWidth=$inputWidth;
    $finalHeight=$inputHeight;

    if ($width>$height){
        $resizeFactor=$finalWidth/$width;

    }
    else{
        $resizeFactor=$finalHeight/$height; 
    }

    $finalWidth=$width*$resizeFactor;
    $finalHeight=$height*$resizeFactor;

    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($finalWidth, $finalHeight);   
    imagecopyresampled($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $finalWidth, $finalHeight, $width, $height);    
    imagejpeg($thumb, $saving_path, 90);
}

if(isset($_POST) == true){
    $fileName = uniqid("p_");
    $title=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['title']);
    $description=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['photodesc']);
    $targetDir = "uploads/";
    $thumbDir = "uploads/thumbs/";
    $targetFile = $targetDir.$fileName;
    $fileExt = pathinfo($targetFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $allowExt = array('jpg','jpeg');

    if(in_array($fileExt, $allowExt){
        makeImage($_FILES['file'], $filename.".jpg", 1000, 1000, $targetDir);
        makeImage($_FILES['file'], $filename.".jpg", 250, 250, $thumbsDir);
        unlink($image['tmp_name']) or die('Warning! Original file could not be deleted!');
        $insertPhotoQuery="INSERT INTO photos (filename, title, description, timestamp) VALUES ('$fileName', '$title', '$description', now())";
        $insertPhotoStatement = mysqli_prepare($conn, $insertPhotoQuery);
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($insertPhotoStatement)){
            $response['status'] = 'ok';
        }
        else{
            $response['status'] = 'err';
        }
    }
    else{
        $response['status'] = 'type_err';
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not canceling the form action, so the page reloads itself (you have an empty `action` attribute, which translates as "on submit, send the form data to the current page").

To cancel the event, add the following inside your `anevase` function, e.g. at the start of it:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Should I add this on the html, in an onsubmit="" attribute?

Comment: Right now it still reloads the page, taking slightly longer (as if it's uploading) but it still shows no image or rows in the database.

Comment: Right then you need to do some step-by-step debugging. If it's still reloading the page then that suggests your function isn't getting called, or it is but with errors. You need to rule out both scenarios. Always check the console. Then try putting some alerts or console.logs at different steps to see where the code is getting to before it runs into a problem. The DB is irrelevant here (or at least it's not the crux of your question) - it's: why is the default form action ocurring when it should be handled by AJAX instead? Regardless of what happens on the server when it gets there.

Comment: Probably something easy to miss. console logs only got me that far - it's not printing in the "else" that contains the xhr code, but it does not print inside the previous "if" conditions either (file size/file type).

Comment: I'm sorry. I just can't work it out. Do you mind dropping another look at my code? I'm guessing it's the jQ script that needs an experienced eye? (I just started learning a few days ago)

Comment: After looking more thoroughly at the errors, it seems that the PHP couldn't capture all of the post data, making the JSON response wrong, which I solved by .append() my relevant fields. However, although I solved an error, it seems there is something else now blocking the script from coming through. I can't catch it though.

Comment: If your issue is that the page reloads, then the PHP is irrelevant in relation to that problem. That's all about your cancellation (or otherwise) of the default form action. It would be hard for me to help without being in your actual environment. If you can set it up as best you can in a Fiddle or CodePen or something similar, I can look further.